# Entity Framework Core / SQLite: GroupJoin after Join "flattens" results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

Using Entity Framework Core 2.1 and an SQLite database, I get different behaviour from a LINQ GroupJoin if I use it after another Join. It is not clear if this is a bug or if there is something I am overlooking.

I have created a minimal VS2017 project to reproduce this, which can be found here:
https://gitlab.com/haddoncd/EntityFrameworkGroupJoinIssue

In this example, I get one object for each row in the Blog table, each containing multiple PostTitles:

```
db.Blogs
    .GroupJoin(
        db.Posts,
        s => s.BlogId,
        p => p.BlogId,
        (s, ps) => new
        {
            s.BlogId,
            s.BlogTitle,
            PostTitles = ps.Select(p => p.PostTitle),
        }
    )
    .OrderBy(x => x.BlogId))
```

But in this example, the results are "flattened" - I get one object for each Blog-Post pair like you would from a conventional SQL outer join:

```
db.Subscriptions
    .Join(
        db.Blogs,
        s => s.BlogId,
        b => b.BlogId,
        (s, b) => new
        {
            s.SubscriptionId,
            b.BlogId,
            b.BlogTitle,
        }
    )
    .GroupJoin(
        db.Posts,
        x => x.BlogId,
        p => p.BlogId,
        (x, ps) => new
        {
            x.SubscriptionId,
            x.BlogTitle,
            PostTitles = ps.Select(p => p.PostTitle),
        }
    )
    .OrderBy(x => x.SubscriptionId))
```

Comment: Great effort in putting all this together but there's some ambiguity remaining: why _wouldn't_ the behavior be different when the input and the join are also different?

Comment: Reproduced. Also the same is happening with SqlServer provider, so it has to be common EF Core query translation bug, hence should be posted here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues

Comment: Thanks, @IvanStoev, I've submitted an issue: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13271